# Wired network connection unstable

Tags: networking, ethernet

For months, I've been using a wireless LAN USB driver on my desktop computer and had no problems with high latency or any errors in the network.

But then, I switched to using the ethernet port. It didn't work at first because my pc doesn't detect the connected cable, I found a (fix?) or a temporary solution to the problem. It's by configuring the LAN settings, specifically changing the **speed and duplex** to 10 Mbps full duplex and then it was fixed.

But after an hour or so, I would get disconnected alot, when I try to -ping in cmd, I often get a **request timeout** even with low ping.

The only temporary fix I find it resetting the speed and duplex again.
But after a day, resetting the configuration doesn't work. I get a **request timeout** every 10 seconds or so.

Comment: A poor connection often indicates that a cable or connection is faulty. Can you make sure that the sockets are clean and try another cable?

Comment: Usually it should be opposite experience, try plug/unplug multiple times ethernet cable to clean up oxidation on contacts, that is most common problem.

Comment: I tried all of the things you guys suggested and it's still the same, low ping but there's always a request timeout, except for trying another cable, I don't have an extra.

Answer (score 0):

We can try the following ways to troubleshoot the issue:

1. Try to change the network cable.
2. Port contact problem with the router or switch.
3. Try to update the NIC driver, if it does not work, maybe NIC aging causes this problem.
4. Other hardware issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you manually configure the port to 10 Mbit/s full-duplex you've deactivated autonegotiation. This causes the switch port to use half-duplex(!), causing a duplex mismatch which will really suck performance-wise and cause lots of errors.

You need to use a proper cable. The cable needs to be at least Cat-5e. If you do have to manually configure down the NIC you either need to configure the switch port to 10M/full-duplex as well or (with an unmanaged switch) configure the NIC for 10M/half-duplex instead.